# post python plot from (IBM Bluemix) to a website and change it automatically

Tags: python, ipython, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook, tone-analyzer

I followed this great tutorial [here](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-hashtags/) , and it works just fine, thanks for Mr.Taieb.

Now, I am interested in post the sentimentDistribution plot (the green bar chart) in a website. I want to make this plot change every 40 seconds so that every 40 seconds Bluemix will stream tweets from twitter and feed the plot on the website.

Is there a python command that I can add to the code below to post the plot to my website instead of just showing it inside the Bluemix ?

```
plt.title('Distribution of tweets by sentiments > 60%')

plt.xticks(ind+width, tweets.columns[-13:])

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Also, how can I make this code run automatically every 40 seconds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Bill, I'm glad to hear that you like the tutorial.

There is currently no easy way to build a real-time dashboard using IPython notebooks. However, if your goal is to create and publish such a dashboard on a web site, then I suggest you look at Part 2 of my tutorial which does exactly that: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/01/15/real-time-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-hashtags-with-spark/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you David , I took a look to your next tutorial  ( the one that build the real-time dashboard ) . It's great. thanks for your effort .I am not interested in finding the hashtags .I am interested to find just the emotions.So, my question is can I do this tutorial without generating the Hashtags trends .I just want to generate the emotions of  all the tweets (like the green chart of the Python notebook ) but in realtime dashboard ? @DavidTaieb

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The source code for both the Spark Streaming app and the front-end node js app is available on Github. You can fork the project and remove the part that shows the trends.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Taieb . Can I change the code on Bluemix after I already deployed your app(your code) ? because after I deployed your app , I had an option on Blumix said :Edit code . Or should I fork the code from the github, edit it , then deploy it again manually ? @DavidTaieb

Comment: @fano: If you are planning to edit the code, I strongly recommend that you clone the project, make changes locally and manually deploy on Bluemix using cf push. You can find detailed instruction for manual deployment: [here](https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/Spark-Twitter-Watson-Dashboard/blob/master/README.md)